# Why class specialization from template<typename T1, typename T2> to template<typename T1, int i> not supported

Tags: c++, templates

I am wondering why class specialization from `template<typename T1, typename T2>` to `template<typename T1, int i>` is not supported.

For example:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct B{};

template<typename T1>
struct B<T1, T1>{};  //ok

template<typename T1>
struct B<T1, int>{}; //ok

template<typename T1,int i>
struct B<T1,i>{}; //error:   expected a type, got 'i'

template<typename T1,constexpr int i>
struct B<T1,i>{}; //error:   expected a type, got 'i'
```

Comment: That's not a specialization...

Comment: Because `i` isn't a type?

Comment: Because there would be little utility and lots of added complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your primary template expects a type parameter, but `i` is not a type, it is a non-type argument.  `int` is a type.

You can use `std::integral_constant` to bind them somehow:

```
template<typename T1, int i>
struct B<T1, std::integral_constant<int, i>>{};
```

It is not exactly the same thing, but a *using declaration* can help to work around it:

```
template<typename T1, int i>
using BT = struct B<T1, std::integral_constant<int, i>>;
```